# How to underline the name of a journal in bibliography without modifying the .bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to underline the name of the journals in my bibliography without modifying the `.bib` file. I'm using BibTeX. I'm not familiar with the packages and syntax that is used in the hacks I've seen posted around.

Comment: Underlining is rather unusual in printed work (it tends to be a 'by hand' indication of italic).

Comment: the `custom-bib` package provides one of the easiest ways to set up your own bibliography style file (.bst) - it certainly allows for italic journal names, but I am not sure that it provides an underlining option. AFAIK underlining cannot be broken across lines - which might cause a problem for automatically doing is for long journal names

Comment: The underlining is a requirement in a paper I have to hand in. custom-bib doesn't suport underlining of journal names. I actually tried to modify the .bib directly but that didn't work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: there is the `ulem` package - it changes emphasized text to underlined - it might work if your journal names are in `\em` rather than `\it`

Comment: Which bibliographical style are you using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina good question. Tell be what `\bibliographystyle` you use and I can post you a new `.bst` file that underlines the journal name. **And one more thing:** You say that modyfing `.bib` file have not helped. Could you please update your question and add one `@article` from your `.bib` file to show what have you unsuccessfully tried?